# Is it possible to use HTML5 local storage to share data between pages from different sites?

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage, same-origin-policy

I would like to create data on the user side and let javascript from another URL access it too. I am aware of the same origin policy, but I was wondering whether it is possible to create some exceptions. Or, is there any trick/feature I could use?

Comment: Is the other URL embedded in an iframe?

Comment: No, it is not embedded.

Comment: The only way I know of is if you are using localstorage in a browser extension or interframe. I'm not sure about IndexedDB though, I haven't played enough with that.

Comment: I don't think you can set any exceptions (maybe something like [`document.domain`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.domain) to circumvent SOP) - you can only load that other site and use cross-origin-messaging to pass the data

Comment: Does this answer your question? [cross domain localstorage with javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33957477/cross-domain-localstorage-with-javascript)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Best trick I know is to use iframes and `postMessage` API do get access to localStorage from external domain.

This technique is quite simple:

- on you page you must create iframe to a domain from which you want to get data
- your data domain need listen to `message` event:

  document.addEventListener ("message", handler, useCapture);
- handler will be responsible for accessing `localStorage` and posting its content to source domain
- your source domain may call `handler` function on data domain with `postMessage` API
  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.postMessage

For security of your data you can use HTTP header **X-Frame-Options ALLOW-FROM uri**
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP/X-Frame-Options?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=The_X-FRAME-OPTIONS_response_header

Hope it will help.