# Why do two web pages have different localStorage? How can I fix this?

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

I'm trying to pass a value from one page to another using localStorage.
Both pages use a common JS file to get/set values from localStorage.
This page sets the value appropriately using `localStorage.setItem('key', 'value')`: http://example.com/path/index.html

`ip` is parsed from the query string and written to localStorage with key `db_ip`.

When I try to do `localStorage.getItem('db_ip')` on this page, then the item is not there: http://www.example.com/path/page.html

I'm reading specs that say ["every Document object whose Window object's localStorage attribute's Storage object is associated with the same storage area"](http://dev.w3.org/html5/webstorage/#the-localstorage-attribute), so this makes me think pages can have separate localStorage by having a different Storage object.

I can see the Storage object is different between the two pages. How to I make both pages use the same Storage object?

Comment: Those are considered different domains (`www` versus no `www`), that's why.

Comment: Nailed it!  Thank you!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The `localStorage` isin't per page, it's by domain. However like @bfavaretto mentionned, *www.demandbaselabs.com* and *demandbaselabs.com* aren't considered as the same domain.

Have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16144906/is-it-possible-to-use-html5-local-storage-to-share-data-between-pages-from-diffe) to see how you can exchange client-side stored data between domains.

Comment: Thank you!!!  What a relief...the code was working, I had just missed the URLs being different.