# localStorage.getItem("base64") is returning null value

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, iframe, google-chrome-extension

I have two files like inject.js and PdfLogin.js.  I have setting the `localStorage.setItem("base64", file)` in *inject.js* file, 
Now i want to get the value of the localstorage in *PdfLogin.js* page and i am using to get the value like this

```
localStorage.getItem("base64")
```

but it is returning "null" value.

How to send and get data from one page (mail.google.com says) to another page (An embedded page at PdfLogin.html says)???

I am using like this

```
localStorage.setItem("base64", file) // mail.google.com page
```

and i'm getting the null value in embedded page at PdfLogin.html

```
localStorage.getItem("base64");
```

Mail ID: **mahendraveeregowda@gmail.com**

Comment: [The localStorage isn't per page, it's by domain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18709523/why-do-two-web-pages-have-different-localstorage-how-can-i-fix-this)

Comment: Content scripts of extensions can use `chrome.storage.local`

Comment: Hi Mario, actually im developing chrome extension, i have written some code to inject my extension to gmail attachments(this is done), now if i click the icon on attachment , i'm getting the base64 string and there only im storing like localStorage.setItem("base64", file), and now i  used to get the value in another page but its return null

Comment: Hi wOxxOm,   Thank you so much for your help, thanks a lot sir,
i'm using like this
 var Base64="";  
 chrome.storage.local.get('Base64', function (result) {
        Base64 = result.Base64;
        alert(result.Base64);
  
    });alert(Base64);   here im getting the first alert message correctly, but outside the function of  **chrome.storage.local.get** alert is undefined, how to use this one because i have to put the value is ajax call

Comment: Hi wOxxOm,
how to store the value of **chrome.storage.local.get** to some variable???
like as ** var abc = localStorage.getItem("key")** alert(abc);

Comment: Look for examples, there are many. In short, chrome.storage is asynchronous so the value should be used only inside the callback.

Comment: @wOxxOm, Thanks for your valuable guidance, its working

Comment: @wOxxOm,  Can i get your mail ID???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not just one page, it's one domain, and that isn't going to work the way it's intended. I presume the situation is that there is a link in a page viewed in an email at mail.google.com, and it's redirecting to your site?  If so, the only mechanism that works is to send the data along with the link in the URL.

Are you generating the message with the URL initially?  What we used to do is encrypt data we needed and added that encrypted string to the end of the URL string.  This then was the URL in the email, and the page received that just fine.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, 
i'm not generating any message with URL, i just want to send the storing value from **mail.google.com** to my site

now i got the solution to send and get the valus across the web page, 

Thank you

Comment: How to open a iframe src inside the parent one like first iframe

Comment: I would post that as a new question, and please include any related code.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to store a complete file, I'm afraid you'll come back empty-handed. For as far as I know, you can only store primitive types in localStorage (e.g. integers, strings,...) and even then they are stringified.

What data are you trying to store?

Comment: Hi Matthias, in localStorage i am storing the base64 encoded string,