# undefined while using getItem

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to send an object between two pages in javascript but I'm getting undefined knowing that I'm using tomcat server
here's the first function in the first page :

```
$http.get('rest/client/authentifier/'+$scope.nouveauClient.numerocompte + '/' + $scope.nouveauClient.mdp)
.then(function(clientresult) {
    window.localStorage.setItem("client",clientresult.data);
    parent.location = "acceuilClient.html";
})
```

here's the second function in the seconde page :

```
var user;

$scope.display = function()
{
    user =  window.localStorage.getItem('client');
    alert("amal  "+user.idclient);
}
```

Comment: Are the URLs different? LocalStorage is domain specific from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16144906/is-it-possible-to-use-html5-local-storage-to-share-data-between-pages-from-diffe).

Comment: No, when I send window.localStorage.setItem("client",clientresult.data.idclient); I get it otherwise I get undefined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot store JavaScript objects as such in [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API/Using_the_Web_Storage_API), only strings.

Whatever you stored in `window.localStorage.setItem("client",clientresult.data);`, you will not retrieve an object with properties.

When calling `user.idclient`, you are calling the `idclient` property on a string, which will yield undefined. Try

```
user =  window.localStorage.getItem('client');
console.log(user)
```

And it may output

> [object Object]

What you need to do is store key/value pairs like:

```
window.localStorage.setItem("idclient", clientresult.data.idclient);
```

You might want to check if the `idclient` exists in `clientresult.data` first.